# Найти два максимальных значения в массиве за минимальное время

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Дана последовательность чисел `A[1], ..., A[n]`.

Нужно найти в этой последовательности два максимальных числа `A[x]` и `A[y]` такие, что

- `A[x] >= A[i]`, где `i <> y`
- `A[y] >= A[i]`, где `i <> x`.

`x` и `y` должны быть различны (`x <> y`). Возможна ситуация, когда `A[x] == A[y]`.

Найти эти два числа за `2n` сравнений можно тривиально.
Однако утверждается, что их можно найти за `n+lg(n)` сравнений.

Я как ни думал, никак не могу придумать, как это можно сделать. На любой алгоритм, который придумывается, можно найти худший случай, который потребует `2n` сравнений.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно найти два максимальных числа за столь малое число сравнений?

Comment: А где утверждается? И в какой формулировке?

Comment: Возможно `n+lg(n)` — это средняя оценка на количество сравнений...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разделим массив на пары чисел и сравним все числа в парах, ставя большее вперед, и помечая меньшее, если был произведен обмен

(например, если числа положительные, можно менять знак, если нет возможности признак сделать - просто дополнительный массив с Bool - про память ведь уговора не было)

Теперь проделаем то же самое для выборки бОльших чисел - с четными индексами, если нумерация с нуля. Повторим для выборки "одно из четырех" и т.д., пока не дойдём до конца. Получился турнир на выбывание, в котором использовано `N` или `N-1` сравнений (Сумма геом. прогрессии `N/2+N/4+N/8+...+1`)

```
2  3  2  6  11  4  1  8
3  2' 6  2' 11  4  8  1' 
6  2' 3' 2' 11  4  8  1`
11 2` 3` 2` 6'  4  8  1`
```

Теперь максимум находится в первой позиции, и за `log(N)` шагов мы можем пройти **по всем позициям, с которым сравнивался максимум**, и выбрать наибольший элемент. Здесь это позиции `4, 6, 5` со значениями `6, 8, 4`, так что второй элемент - 8